# flexslider2 - add slide appears to work, but slide li not being added

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am trying to use the addSlide feature of flexslider2 and can't seem to get it working.  On page load there is one slide in the dom.  I then dynamically add slides using ajax.  All ajax is performing correctly, but the slide addition is not.

I have doctored up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/66fUv/2/ which does not use ajax, but replicates the same issues.

I have been playing around with this for hours now...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <select id="dtRefresh" class="form-control input-small select2me">
                <option value="16">15 seconds</option>
                <option value="31" selected="selected">30 seconds</option>
                <option value="61">1 minute</option>
                <option value="121">2 minutes</option>
                <option value="301">5 minutes</option>
            </select>
            <label class="control-label"> refresh rate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-top-15 clearfix">
            <button id="dtStart" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> &nbsp;Start Real-time Updates</button>
            <button id="dtStop" type="button" class="hide btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i> &nbsp;Stop Real-time Updates </button>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> &nbsp;Viewer Refresh : <span id="dtTimer">Paused</span></button>
            </div>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul id="ss-slider" class="slides">
                <li>default slide</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
// slider load function
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",              
    animationSpeed: 400,
    slideshow: false
});


var slider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider');
var timerId;
var timerStatus;

// start timer
$('#dtStart').on('click', function () {
    if(timerStatus != true) {
        var timerCount = $('#dtRefresh').val();
        $("#dtStart").addClass('hide');
        $("#dtStop").removeClass('hide');
    }

    function countdown(count) {             
        if(timerStatus != true) {
            timerStatus = true;
            timerId = setInterval(function() {
                count--;
                $("#dtTimer").html(count);
                if(count == 0) {
                    $("#dtTimer").html(count);
                    count = timerCount;


                    //add the slide
                    slider.addSlide('<li>added</li>', slider.count + 1);

                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    countdown(timerCount);    
});

//stop timer
$('#dtStop').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerStatus = false;
    $("#dtTimer").html('Paused');
    $("#dtStart").removeClass('hide');
    $("#dtStop").addClass('hide');  
});
```

**UPDATE:**
I have found that if you do not provide a position when adding a slide it defaults to the end.  I also have it working as expected when using 'slide', but it still does not work at all when using 'fade' which is what I would like to use.

updated fiddle using slide - [updated fiddle with slide](http://jsfiddle.net/66fUv/3/)

You can view the above and change to 'fade' to see what I am talking about.  The slides simply do not show.  Perhaps this is a css issue?  Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.flex-active-slide{
    display:block !important;
}
```

solves the issue when using fade.

Answer (score 0):

Your may try this..

```
var slider = $('.flexslider').flexslider();
var ssIndex = $(".slides li").length ;
slider.addSlide('<li>test</li>', ssIndex);
```

If you are not getting with this..please create a jsFiddle or explain more..

Comment: added a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/66fUv/2/ - the gist is one slide is there on page load and when the timer reaches zero a new slide is added to the END of the ul.